# A weird bad request error

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-post

I want to get runners' information from here: http://results.nyrr.org/event/M2016/finishers. I send a post request to get the information for a single runner (in this case, the first one):

```
request = requests.post('http://results.nyrr.org/api/runners/resultDetails', {'runnerId': 11585036})
```

The problem is that I get `Response [400]`, a bad request error. However, if I go to the website, click on the runner, and run again the post request, I get `Response [200]` with the information I want.

I want all runners' information, so I cannot click on each of them before using the post request. Why I am having this error? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs smoothly in my computer:

```
>>> requests.post('http://results.nyrr.org/api/runners/resultDetails', {'runnerId': 11585036})
<Response [200]>
```

[image: screenshot]

So I can only guess why your code isn't working.

Here is a normal request by a browser:

```
POST http://results.nyrr.org/api/runners/resultDetails HTTP/1.1
Host: results.nyrr.org
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Username: subscriber
Origin: http://results.nyrr.org
Password: umPrcNcZKuJ9TQ2
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://results.nyrr.org/event/M2016/result/2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: __cfduid=d518b5aad8e36a9f400b27bbf4355f42e1503820652; ARRAffinity=d217e26f983a10c0f58203f7743dc44212160b2fbe97e9354b4a7b599e51a221; __atuvc=2%7C35; __atuvs=59a27b785f22cb33001

{"runnerId":11585036}
```

Compared with the request sent by your python code, we can see the following differences:

- The normal request sends parameters using JSON, while your code sends parameters in form format.
- The normal request includes some headers like `User-Agent` and `Referer`, which are often used to perform anti-scraping.
- The normal request has a `Username` and `Password` header generated by the JS code. Absolutely it is used for anti-scraping, but I don't know why this is not working.

And then here is the advises I can give to you:

- Send the parameter in JSON format. Like: `requests.post('http://...', json={'runnerId': 11585036})`
- Add more headers. Like: `requests.post('http://...', json=..., headers={'User-Agent':'...', ...})`
- Use `selenium` if you are still banned by the anti-scraping techniques.

Answer (score 0):

When you download from website you send some cookies along with the request. Check which cookies are sent from 'Developers tools' in your browser and send the same with `requests.post`.